# Different FORM VIEWS available from a list's Open Menu (Ellipsis)?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath, form, edit

I believe I've seen this done before, but I'm not actually sure how to do it myself.  I have multiple InfoPath forms created for a list, and I wanted to see how to go about being able to access these different forms from the list item's Open Menu (the ellipsis that appears on a list item, in order to edit, view, etc).  At the moment, I only have one content type (if that matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Custom List Item Menu using SharePoint Designer.

Open the Site using the SharePoint Designer->Select the list where you would like to create the list action menu->Custom Action Button -> “List Item Menu” to create the custom list action item:

[image]

Reference:

https://nikpatel.net/2010/08/03/create-custom-list-item-menu-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/

Comment: Thank you very much.